# Какой конструктор мне нужно реализовать, чтоб объект можно было инициализировать через присваивание?

Tags: c++, ооп, конструктор

Не моуг инициализировать объект с помощью оператора присваивания, компилятор выдает ошибку `/home/anton/Programming/RoboCone/RoboCone/main.cpp:29: ошибка: no matching constructor for initialization of 'SocketClient'`.
Выдает вот в этой строчке  `SocketClient client = server.Listen();`
Server.Listen возвращает экземпляр объекта SocketClient(по значению).
Вот список реализованных в SocketClient конструкторов

```
SocketClient::SocketClient(int serverDescriptor, bool block){
    sockaddr_storage client_addr;
    socklen_t s_size = sizeof(client_addr);
    socket_ = accept(serverDescriptor, (sockaddr*)&client_addr, &s_size);
    if (block == false)
        fcntl(socket_, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
}

SocketClient::SocketClient(SocketClient &other){
    this->socket_ = other.socket_;
}


SocketClient::SocketClient(){
    socket_ = false;
}
```

Так же реализован оператор присваивания

```
 SocketClient& SocketClient::operator=(const SocketClient& other){
    this->socket_ = other.socket_;
     return *this;
}
```

Вот код Server.Listen

```
SocketClient SocketServer::Listen(){
    SocketClient client(socket_);
    return client;
}
```

Comment: В записи `SocketClient client = server.Listen();` оператор присваивания не вызывается. А в операторе присваивания инициализация производиться не может. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: @user7860670, Ну так есть же еще конструктор копирования, он, вроде, должен вызываться в таком случае. И конструктор по умолчанию есть, я не понимаю, почему он не инициализирует объект

Comment: Аргументы в конструкторе копирования неправильные `SocketClient::SocketClient(SocketClient &other)`. Нужно добавить **const**. `SocketClient::SocketClient(SocketClient const &other)`

Comment: Вы написали конструктор, который принимает только **lvalue** объекты, а результат **Listen** даёт **rvalue**.